# Prevent a number from being the first character in a string with preg_match()

Tags: php, regex

This code works to allow only alphanumeric characters but I want to prevent `$name` from starting with a number. How do I do this?

```
$name = "007_jamesbond";

if(preg_match('/[^a-z_\-0-9]/i', $name)){
 echo "invalid name";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it. Also `\w` is alphanumeric characters and underscores.

```
$name = "007\_jamesbond";
if(preg_match('/(^\d|[^\-\w])/', $name)){
    echo "invalid name";
}
```

Output:

> invalid name

Regex101 Demo: https://regex101.com/r/dF0zQ1/1

**Update**

Should account for decimals and negative numbers as well...

```
$name = "007\_jamesbond";
if(preg_match('/(^[.\-]?\d|[^\-\w])/', $name)){
    echo "invalid name";
}
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/dF0zQ1/2

Comment: I went with your first version. It doesn't allow decimals or negative numbers. I also modified it to not allow hyphens.

Answer (score 1):

It may be clearer to define a pattern for what *is* valid, and check for things that *do not* match it.

```
if(!preg_match('/^[a-z][a-z_\-0-9]*/i', $name)){
   echo "invalid name";
}

//               ^                    anchor to beginning of string
//                 [a-z]              a letter (add underscore here if it's ok too)
//                      [a-z_\-0-9]*  any number of alphanumeric+underscore characters
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$name = "007_jamesbond";

if(preg_match('/^[^a-z]/i', $name)){
    echo "invalid name";
}
```

The `^` at the start of a regex means "The start of the string". This regex can be read as: "If `$name` starts (`^`) with a character that is not a-z (`[^a-z]`), it is invalid."

If you want a single regex to match both requirements ("only alphanum, doesn't start with non-letter"), you can use this:

```
/(^[^a-z]|[^\w\-])/
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this: (without using regex)

```
$first = substr($name, 0,1);
if(is_numeric($first))
{
    echo 'the first character cannot be numeric';
}
else
{
    if(preg_match('/[^a-z_\-0-9]/i', $name))
    {
        echo 'invalid name';
    }
}
```